# How to read a SecretKey from a p12 file?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I'm trying to read the SecretKey from a p12 file, but it is not created in Bouncy Castle. A interesting thing to note is that file doesn't have any certificate and the class System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates can't read anything.

```
  public void Pkcs12Pfx2()
    {
        Pfx bag = Pfx.GetInstance(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        ContentInfo info = bag.AuthSafe;
        MacData mData = bag.MacData;
        DigestInfo dInfo = mData.Mac;
        AlgorithmIdentifier algId = dInfo.AlgorithmID;
        byte[] salt = mData.GetSalt();
        int itCount = mData.IterationCount.IntValue;

        Asn1OctetString content = Asn1OctetString.GetInstance(info.Content);
        AuthenticatedSafe authSafe = AuthenticatedSafe.GetInstance(content.GetOctets());
        ContentInfo[] c = authSafe.GetContentInfo();

        foreach (ContentInfo ci in c)
        {
            DerObjectIdentifier oid = ci.ContentType;

            byte[] octetsCi = null;
            if (oid.Equals(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Data))
            {
                octetsCi = Asn1OctetString.GetInstance(ci.Content).GetOctets();
            }

            if (octetsCi != null)
            {
                Asn1Sequence seqCi = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(octetsCi);

                foreach (Asn1Sequence subSeq in seqCi)
                {
                    SafeBag bagCi = SafeBag.GetInstance(subSeq);

                    foreach (var item in Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(bagCi.BagValue))
                    {
                        if (item.Equals(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PrivateKeyInfo pki = new PrivateKeyInfo(algId, (Asn1Encodable)item);
                            var epki = EncryptedPrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreateEncryptedPrivateKeyInfo("PBEWITHSHA1AND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC", password.ToCharArray(), salt, itCount, pki);

                            var aa = epki.ToAsn1Object();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The object epki contains the information of the SecretKey, but it still encrypted, or encoded. How can I decode that information?

Answer (score 2):

If you just look to open the file and get the key it is much more simple using the `Pkcs12Store` class. You provide the file and the file password to open it. Then once you create the object you have a property `Aliases` will list aliases for all entries in the file. Then you just call the 'GetKey` method with an alias name to get the key for the entry.

Here is a sample of how to read the key for the first entry.

```
 Pkcs12Store pkcs12Store = new Pkcs12Store(new FileStream("test.p12", FileMode.Open), "password".ToCharArray());
 AsymmetricKeyEntry key = pkcs12Store.GetKey(pkcs12Store.Aliases.Cast<string>().First());
 RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)key.Key; // here you should check what kind of key it is to then access the specific key parameters
```

Comment: I tested something similar but it don't work too. When I look in pkcs12Store object it can't get any Alias, only the number of the algorithms are loaded. I don't know if it is because the file don't have a certificate.

Comment: I don't think so because the file format says it can also be also just keys. Are you sure this is a valid pkcs12 file? How is it created?

Comment: I was not informed how it was created, and probably I will not be. (That's sad...). 
But when I put the file in [lapo.it](https://lapo.it/asn1js) or using certutil: 
`certutil -v -p pass -privatekey -dumpPFX .\key.p12` 
it can be read.

Comment: Can you export your private key using openssl: `openssl.exe pkcs12 -in test.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem`?